# Multiple ssh in a Single command

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, redhat, cut

I need to pipe multiple ssh commands in order to run commands on a remote machine.
The commands are working fine with a single ssh but not after piping ssh.
E.g

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com "a=hello ; echo \$a"
```

return hello
but

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com ssh abc@remotemachine2.com"a=hello ; echo \$a"
```

produces no output.

Similarly:

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com "mountedDir=\$(df \tmp | grep -vi filesystem | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1); mount | grep -w \$mountedDir"
```

Is working fine producing the following output :

```
/dev/sda2 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

but

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com ssh abc@remotemachine2.com "mountedDir=\$(df \tmp | grep -vi filesystem | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1); mount | grep -w \$mountedDir"
```

is throwing the following error:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Note: Passwordless ssh is established from my machine to remotemachine1.com and from remotemachine1.com to remotemachine2.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked after I added multiple escape characters

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com " ssh abc@remotemachine2.com \" a=hello ;echo \\\$a \" "
```

And

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com " ssh abc@remotemachine2.com \" mountedDir=\\\$(df /var | grep -vi filesystem | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1); mount | grep -w \\\$mountedDir | grep -vi 'noexec'  \" "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh abc@remotemachine1.com ssh abc@remotemachine2.com"a=hello ; echo \$a"
```

Looks wrong. If you want to jump from remotemachine1 to remotemachine2 have a look at the `ProxyJump` option in the ssh config. You can give it on the command line using the `-o` option of the ssh binary.

Comment: I'm not trying to connect to multiple machines.
i'm trying to execute commands on remotemachine2.com which has got ssh enabled only from remotemachine1.com .

Comment: So you are trying to jump from machine1 to machine2? Then use ProxyJump. You add  ``ProxyJump remotemachine1`` to the Host section for ``remotemachine2`` in your ``.ssh/config`` or ``/etc/ssh/ssh_config`` file.

Comment: I actually don't want to edit ssh config files so proxy jump is out of question..

Comment: And giving it on the command line of the ssh program isn't an option either?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you do not want to modify your `ssh_config` file, you need to use `ssh -t` which will cause a real TTY to be allocated on machine 2, like so:

```
ssh -t abc@remotemachine1.com ssh abc@remotemachine2.com"a=hello ; echo \$a"
```

Be wary, as using this method implies that all the SSH login authentication procedures will happen at `remotemachine1.com`, so if you have security concerns, you are better off with @allo 's answer.

Comment: Didn't help, as still produced no output. Also, passwordless ssh is established from my machine to remotemachine1.com and from remotemachine1.com to remotemachine2.com

Comment: When you insist on giving the argument to the ssh binary, you need to use proper quoting. This means the second ssh command needs to be in quotes and the commands for the second machine need to be in escaped quotes.

Comment: tried all possible quotes combinations.. " inside ' , ' inside ' , \" inside " ..
None of them is working...